# Converting Array of Python dictionaries to Python dictionary using comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a Python array of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "pins": [1,2],
  "group": "group1"
 },
 {
  "pins": [3,4],
  "group": "group2"
 }
]
```

I want to convert this array of dictionaries into the following dictionary:

```
{ 1: "group1", 2: "group1", 3: "group2", 4: "group2" }
```

I wrote the following double for loop to accomplish this, but was curious if there is a more efficient way to do this (maybe a comprehension?):

```
new_dict = {}
for d in my_array:
    for pin in d['pins']:
        new_dict[pin] = d['group']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try a dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {
    k : arr['group'] for arr in my_array for k in arr['pins']
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_dict = {}
for arr in my_array:
    for k in arr['pins']:
        new_dict[k] = arr['group']
```

```
print(new_dict)
{1: 'group1', 2: 'group1', 3: 'group2', 4: 'group2'}
```